# ElasticSearch AND operation on complexType Object Fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elastic search Index with the following mappings:

```
{
"index_one": {
    "mappings": {
        "uidMapping": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "_source": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
                "age": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "clean_url": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": false,
                    "fields": {
                        "hash": {
                            "type": "murmur3"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "gender": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "segment_aggregate": {
                    "properties": {
                        "segment_name": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "segment_value": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url_md5": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": false
                },
                "url_page_views": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "index": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to run queries with an AND operation on the segment_aggregate fields, ie, queries results should only be returned when both conditions are met. So far, With BoolQueryBuilders, I have tried Match queries and terms queries in Must Clauses, but always seem to get results with an or operation between segment_name and segment_value.

```
 BoolQueryBuilder queryTest = new BoolQueryBuilder();  
 queryTest.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("segment_aggregate.segment_name", 
 "AnyValue").operator(Operator.AND));

queryTest.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("segment_aggregate.segment_value", 
"A").operator(Operator.AND));

parentQuery.must(queryTest);
```

This returns an OR result for the two fields, basically the larger subset.
Also Tried:

```
mustQuery.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("segment_aggregate.segment_name", "SegmentName"));
mustQuery.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("segment_aggregate.segment_value", "SegmentValue"));
```

This too doesn't yield desires results.
Even when I tried wrapping the subqueries with must clauses in another query, and adding to parent query, this approach too didn't work.

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is probably because you are not marking the segment_aggregate type as **nested**.

By default, all fields are independently indexed.  Even though the JSON structure looks like you are associating specific values inside the inner object in segment_aggregate together, really ES is creating an index of values for **segment_aggregate.segment_name** and a separate index for **segment_aggregate.segment_value**.

This means when you do a search like this (assuming query string):

```
segment_aggregate.segment_name:color AND segment_aggregate.segment_value:green
```

what Elasticsearch is really doing is searching for a document where ANY of the values in **segment_aggregate.segment_name** are set to "color" and ANY of the values in **segment_aggregate.segment_value** are set to "green".  To tell Elasticsearch you want to use the association between the fields in the inner object you need to mark **segment_aggregate's** type as "nested" instead of the default of "object".  Also, you will need to use the special nested query and nested aggregation parts of the query DSL.

More details can be found here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: Hi Ryan, I thought of it too, but when I tried something like: QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("segment_aggregate", // Path
      QueryBuilders.boolQuery() // Your query
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("segment_aggregate.segment_name", segmentName))
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("segment_aggregate.segment_value", "A")))
      .scoreMode("max");


Elastic search threw exceptions.
Do I need to change mappings for the index as well?

Comment: Yes, you need to explicitly set the type in the mapping on segment_aggregate to "nested".

Comment: Accepted answer. Working fine after changing index mappings.